# How to wait finish recursive loop then only echo?

Tags: php

```
function test_loop($x, $y)
{
    static $x_values = array(); 
    $x = $x + 1;
    if($x < 10)
    {
         $x_values[] = $x."#"; // insert item 2#,3#,4# into array
    }

    //loop again if y is not = 3;
    $y = $y + 1;
    if($y < 5)
    {
        test_loop($x, $y); 
    }

    echo "gula</br>";
    return $x_values; 
}

function abc(){
    $bababa = test_loop(1,0);

    foreach($bababa as $fpackage_id)
    {
        echo $fpackage_id;
    }
}

abc();
```

Output :

```
gula
gula
gula
gula
gula
2#3#4#5#6#
```

The code call test_loop() function before echo "gula", so supposedly it should fail to echo "gula". How to make the Output become like below :

```
gula
2#3#4#5#6#
```

**UPDATE :**
I tried to move the echo and return into else{} statement as @Joel Hager suggested, end up no output on the return value.

```
function test_loop($x, $y)
{
    static $x_values = array(); 
    $x = $x + 1;
    if($x < 10)
    {
         $x_values[] = $x."#"; // insert item 2#,3#,4# into array
    }

    //loop again if y is not = 3;
    $y = $y + 1;
    if($y < 5)
    {
        test_loop($x, $y); 
    }else{
        echo "gula</br>";
        return $x_values; 
    }

}
```

Comment: It prints `gula` *every* time `test_loop()` is called, so you get one line for every `n#` added to the array.

Comment: You're echoing `gula` every time it runs, as it's not wrapped in any conditional. It's just choosing whether to push or rerun, but the echo is in every iteration of the function. If you want it to be final, you could put an `else` and echo there right before the final output.

Comment: since if($y < 5) { test_loop($x, $y);  } is executed before it prints gula, supposely it wont have chance to prints gula

Comment: You would have to return from that. Add a `return` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a return statement on you recursive call to `test_loop`

```
    if($y < 5)
    {
        return test_loop($x, $y); 
    }
```

This way the code execution goes back to test_loop.

Comment: perfect. You are life saver. Thank you very much.